# Transitive dependency missing in development mode

Tags: gradle, quarkus

In a simple REST service built with Quarkus, a *ClassNotFoundException* is thrown if the service is run in development mode. With the uber-jar, it works correctly.

How can I get the service working in development mode too?

The missing class belongs to a transitive dependency of a QR bill generator library, which is declared `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'net.codecrete.qrbill:qrbill-generator:2.2.2'
    ...
}
```

The error occurs in development mode (`gradle quarkusDev`) only. It is triggered if a REST request would need to use the *qrbill:qrbill-generator* library:

```
2020-05-03 12:11:49,463 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /xxx/yyy failed, error id: 89c5b7f8-c762-4f7f-959b-67f16b2bc120-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/nayuki/qrcodegen/QrCode$Ecc
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:216)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:515)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
[several lines omitted]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/nayuki/qrcodegen/QrCode$Ecc
        at net.codecrete.qrbill.generator.QRCode.draw(QRCode.java:49)
        at net.codecrete.qrbill.generator.BillLayout.drawPaymentPart(BillLayout.java:131)
        at net.codecrete.qrbill.generator.BillLayout.draw(BillLayout.java:94)
[several lines omitted]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.nayuki.qrcodegen.QrCode$Ecc
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:341)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:294)
        ... 44 more
```

When analyzing the dependencies, I can see that *io.nayuki:qrcodegen:1.6.0* is part of the *runtimeClasspath* but not part of the *compileClasspath*. This looks ok.

Could it be that Quarkus dev mode uses the wrong classpath?

Comment: Does the issue persist after running ```gradle clean```?

Comment: @PieterjanDeconinck Yes, it persists.

Comment: Which version of Quarkus is this?

Comment: The latest stable version: 1.4.1.Final

Comment: Can you open a github issue? It looks like something worth investigating

Comment: @geoand Issue opened: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9030